# can a domain name containing the symbol ø?

Tags: dns

I want to buy a domain that has this symbol in it: ø . However some sites say that it is not possible while others say it is. Is it safe to buy a domain with this symbol? and who should I buy it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS only supports ASCII characters.  You can buy an [IDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) (Internationalized Domain Name) with non-ASCII characters in it, like `ø`, but it has to encoded using [Punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) when stored in the DNS system.  So, for example, if you have `mydømain.com`, it would be encoded as `xn--mydmain-s1a.com`.  Many domain registrars do support IDNs, but not all do.